# Ruby on Rails. Views showing full objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my views are showing full objects like so:

`dbwest hi [#<Tweet id: 1, tweet: "hi", created_at: "2013-05-25 12:16:40", updated_at: "2013-05-25 12:16:40", user_id: 1>]`

I just want
`dbwest hi`

Has anybody else every seen something like this?

---

more code I'm pasting on request:

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
```

changing it to

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have something like `<%= @tweet = Tweet.first %>` which would display the whole object in your view, when  you mean to just "find the first tweet" `<% @tweet = Tweet.first %>` With no code it's hard, but that is in essence what is happening. If anyone reading on the web, don't find in a view this way. Again, not saying  this guy is but bad form. stuff that spit in the controller and reference the ivar `@tweet` later in your view.

Comment: You nailed it. That was it.